# Why does V8 not run with SDL threads?

Tags: c++, javascript, sdl, multithreading

i was able to compile and link V8 against my game and code interpretation works fine. However I want to divide my code and the game loop should exist in one thread and the scripting engine should run in a second thread alongside my game loop. I am using SDL and therefore tried this code to spawn a new thread

```
SDL_CreateThread(ScriptingEngine::SpawnMain, NULL);
```

where the following code is my test scripting engine:

```
namespace ScriptingEngine {
    v8::HandleScope handleScope;
    v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New();
    v8::Persistent<v8::Context> context;

    void Setup() {
            // TODO: bind functions to global
            // ...
            context = v8::Context::New(NULL, global);
    }

    int SpawnMain(void *arguments) {
            v8::Context::Scope scope(context);
            v8::Handle<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(
                    v8::String::New("'Hello World'")
            );
            v8::Handle<v8::Value> result = script->Run();
            context.Dispose();
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

However I get an error like `Access violation reading location 0x00000000.` in `api.cc` line 716: `i::Isolate* isolate = env->GetIsolate();`.

Has anyone a clue how I can fix this or what the exact problem is?

Comment: +1 for coming back with the answer. You should really answer your own question so you can mark it as answered (the S/O team encourage answering your own questions if you can).

Comment: @JonathanDickinson: I have not enough reputation and therefore I am blocked for 8 hours until I a able to answer my own question. I will do this tomorrow ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## ***Solution***

The solution was to use a monitor like `v8::Locker locker;`. Exactly this line must be entered the line before the creation of the `HandleScope` and it should work, although my code up there is crap. I have combined all variables etc. into one method without a `setup` method or the variables in `ScriptingEngine`.

Long story short: the `Locker` object is responsible for thread management as the engine isolates itself for sandboxing purposes.

Comment: Sometimes this SO rep thing is silly for decent users :).